# How to remove time info from WCF messages?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, security, binding, clock-synchronization

I was trying to set maxclockskew for a secure service being consumed in a Silverlight client.

The things I tried have been summarized in related post
[How to fix the WCF maxClockSkew problem in a HTTPS Silverlight application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971785/how-to-fix-the-wcf-maxclockskew-problem-in-a-https-silverlight-application-contex)

As I also have found no way to do that, now I also want to remove the timeinfos, so that clock-skew validation is skipped. How is it done?
just setting the InclueTimestamp to false didn't work.